# Kibana dashboard is showing the status as "RED" where as cluster health using curl command is showing status as "GREEN" for ElasticSearch

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, kibana

I have started to learn ElasticSearch. I install ElasticSearch 5.6.8 and Kibana version 5.x
When I view the status of the cluster using curl command "curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_cat/health?v"" it shows "Green" as shown below:

[image: terminal output using curl]

But when I view it on browser using "http://localhost:5601" it shows status as "RED" as shown below:

[image: Kibana Browser]

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates you're running a newer version of Kibana and an older, incompatible version of Elasticsearch

```
plugin:kibana@6.2.3
```

Solution is either grab the latest release of Elasticsearch, or downgrade Kibana

Personally, I use [Docker Compose](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk) to test ELK stack locally